# Is there any reason that bootstrap supports only event emitting, rather than callback patterns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, callback, event-handling

In [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) [javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) section, many of things supports event emitter, like *shown.bs.modal* for modal shown.

But this makes itchy to implement situations that need to perform different behavior in event handler.

Here's some example: there is a *myModal*, and two buttons, *myBtn1* and *myBtn2* can trigger the modal to be shown. When the modal is shown by *myBtn1*, an alert should be raised.

There are many possible solutions:

- [using timeout](http://jsfiddle.net/theeluwin/r7Qa2/6/)
- [using event handler, with global variable](http://jsfiddle.net/theeluwin/8Vagr/1/)
- [using event handler, with tag attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/theeluwin/9uFsp/1/) (this is similar to above one)

But this is how it should be:

```
$("#myBtn1").click(function(e){
    $("#myModal").modal({
        show: true,
        onShown: function(e){
            alert("myModal shown by myBtn1");
        }
    });
});
$("#myBtn2").click(function(e){
    $("#myModal").modal({
        show: true
    });
});
```

How do you guys think about this? Is there any reason that bootstrap is avoiding callback pattern? Will this kind of thing can be suitable feature request?

Comment: Why would you want to initialize the same modal more than once? if you want to change an option, change an option. but what you are suggesting for it to be simply doesn't make sense. It's one modal, it either has a shown event or it doesn't, you cant make it have or not have an event based on which button was clicked.

Comment: @KevinB Then can I ask why it should not have such thing? I needed such situation like having different events depending on context. I've made my work done using one of the the tricks I've written above (fiddles), but I thought that if there were some kinda way to implement those like callback style I wrote, it might be more convenient.

Comment: Um, come to think about it, the part "initializing the same modal more than once" you talked about, IS not good.. maybe I'll think more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the modal outside, then bind to the event as needed.

```
$("#myModal").modal({
    show: true
});

$("#myBtn1").click(function(e){
    $("#myModal").one('shown', function(){
        alert("myModal shown by myBtn1");
    }).modal("show");
});
$("#myBtn2").click(function(e){
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
```

This assumes showing the modal generates a normal jquery custom event. If it doesn't, you can add a callback to the modal that triggers the event. then, your buttons simply listen to for on demand.

Comment: Okay this is nice solution. So is this feature not strong enough for feature request since there are too many alternative solutions?

Comment: well, what exactly is the "feature" you want to implement? in my opinion you were using it wrong completely (in that you were initializing it more than once.) Once you stop doing that, the only "feature" left is whether or not it raises an event, which i do think it should raise an event if it isn't already.

Comment: Duplicating the initialization is my mistake. The "feature" I want to say is, just having different behavior of event handler depending on the context. Actually I've questioned similar thing before ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108990/how-do-you-guys-think-about-respective-callback-for-bootstrap-modal-triggers)). Since I'm not really good at questioning nor programming, maybe I'll think again more deeply and re-upload with more valid question. Thanks a lot really.

Comment: Well, the modal should not need to know about it's context, that violates separation of concerns (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) That's why the best solution is to have the modal emit an event (which it should and probably does), not caring what intercepts that event. Then, you can use that event to accomplish your goal (which is what my answer does.) In my answer, you have one modal, and two buttons. You end up with different behavior for each button based on how you listen to the event raised by the modal.

Comment: Well that helps a lot. Never new about the policy. Okay, now I really get the point. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Sorry to bother you @KevinB, here is final form of what I've wanted. I do understand about separation of concerns, just telling that this is the point I was talking about. I forked bootstrap [here](https://github.com/theeluwin/bootstrap), [this](https://github.com/theeluwin/bootstrap/commit/d48ca2b9ab787fec695b6b44b362844c3438df4e) is what I've changed, and it works like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/theeluwin/dva6L/1/).

Comment: Doing that does keep it encapsulated, that's a good compromise.